# How are these sentences relatable?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read these sentences in a chapter in my book which was "Journey to the end of the Earth":

> It's an immersion that will force you to place yourself in the context of the earth's geological history. And for humans the prognosis isn't good.

I don't know whether it is my bad habit or good that I am always keen to relate sentences to the premises before them. But I'm unable to relate these sentences with any logical sense. In the first, a description of something magnificent is given. But the second one with the word prognosis doesn't relate to the first for me. Prognosis means forecast and I wanna ask of what which I think is unclear from the first.

Comment: The writer is assuming that contextualizing humanity (short-lived, both as individuals and as a distinct *life-form*) within ***geological*** time inevitably forces you to see that *most* life-forms / species don't last all that long compared to geological phenomena (I bet there aren't many species as old as the Himalayas! :) Effectively, the "prognosis" is contextually relevant to what can be seen coming for humanity (almost inevitable extinction, based on what happens to everything else).

Comment: We would need more context to know exactly what the author implies.  Is this the book about the author's trip to Antarctica?

Comment: @Andrew- Yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "It is an immersion"

It is not clear without further context what "it" refers to. Probably a metaphorical "immersion".

> "will force you to place yourself in the context of the Earth's geological history"

The Earth's geological history is 4.7 billion years long. This will make you think of your short life in this very long history.

> For humans the prognosis isn't good.

When you look on the scale of the Earth's geological history, you will realise that Humans can't expect to continue as a species forever. We will probably soon be wiped out by some natural (or man-made) disaster.

We make a prediction or prognosis based on the past history of the Earth.

Comment: I don't think "book" is "it" in the sentence. Link to the chapter- https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://cdn.s3waas.gov.in/s347d1e990583c9c67424d369f3414728e/uploads/2018/02/2018031669-1.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjNqYf5vJLiAhVYinAKHeMyDZsQFjAGegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw1AZtgpU-M5xMHVrBeHyRQN&cshid=1557543359838

Comment: @Kelvin I immediately spotted "Biginning" in that text, which is a bad sign. The text that you quote also doesn't appear anywhere in the linked introduction.